# WordPress Menu Background Color

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to change the color of my menu background to black so it matches the black of the header on top. https://pelev.co.uk/ is my website, I use Neve theme. I tried changing some stuff in the style.css of the theme but it didn't really work. Thank you!

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/3vgGrsz

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste these rules into your style.css file:

```
.hfg_header .header-bottom-inner {
    background-color: #000000!important;
}
```

and

```
.builder-item--primary-menu .nav-menu-primary > .primary-menu-ul li:not(.woocommerce-mini-cart-item) > a {
    color: #ffffff!important;
}
```

Comment: it is still not working, I added both into the style.css of my theme